# CFG gammar for interrogative statement

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

Using the below grammar I can chunk declarative statement which it has noun phrase and verb phrase, how can I modify the below grammar to chunk the interrogative statement from it?

```
grammar = r"""
  NP: {<DT|JJ|NN.*>+}         
  PP: {<IN><NP>}               
  VP: {<VB.*><NP|PP|CLAUSE>+$} 
  CLAUSE: {<NP><VP>}
  """
```